# AWS Athena create table from select query

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am trying to create table using the query below. If I do not create table, but just run the part from SELECT *, the query can be run.

```
    (SELECT *
    FROM "MyDatabase"."2007" A
    WHERE A."column name a" NOT IN ('U','A+','A','A-')
            AND A."column name b" NOT IN ('SHH','CTP')
            AND NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT *
        FROM "MyDatabase"."2008" B
        WHERE (B."column name a" = A."column name a"
                AND B."column name b" = A."column name b"
                AND B."column name c" = A."column name c")))
```

The error message is "GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'partOfAColName' at line 1:..."

From google search, space in column names seems to be the problem. But I am not sure. I have space in column names. The column names are automatically detected by Glue Crawler. So I am not sure if I can do anything about it. I have around 20 columns, all having space in the middle though. Could someone suggest a fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When you execute CREATE TABLE AS...you are telling Athena to create a table with the same column names in your SELECT, but in this case those column names contain spaces, and Athena won't allow you to create a column name with a space. To avoid this you can create the table with column names that adhere to the Athena's specifications then populate that table with INSERT INTO SELECT...FROM

Comment: To me what happened was that i could create and run an DDL create table statement with spaces contained in their columns but now i  cannot insert rows ;/

Comment: wow thanks.  what a horrible way to report that error - i naturally thought it was an issue in the data itself!